# Trying to use DateTime. What's wrong?

Tags: perl

I am trying to get `DateTime` to out todays date in `%d/%m-%Y'` format, but I get `undef`.

What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

use DateTime ();
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $now   = DateTime->now;

my $p = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
    pattern     => '%d/%m-%Y',
    time_zone   => 'UTC',
    );

my $dt = $p->parse_datetime($now);

print Dumper $dt;
```

Comment: I think you're trying to parse the time, from $now, while you want the opposite.

Comment: yes, strftime stands for string format time, strptime stands for string parse time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be written as simple as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use DateTime ();

my $now = DateTime->now( 'time_zone' => 'UTC' );
print $now->strftime('%d/%m-%Y');
```

Comment: What does the `()` in `use DateTime ();` actually do? I have seen it several times.

Comment: The `()` explicitly states that the _@EXPORT_ -s (if any) of `DateTime` should not be imported. For example, if `DateTime` _@EXPORT_ -ed a function named `end_of_world_time` and `use DateTime ();` is in effect, to invoke the function, one will have to qualify the function with its package name: `DateTime::end_of_world_time`. However, if you `use DateTime;`, you will be able to invoke the function by calling: `end_of_world_time` without the need for qualifying it with its package name.

Comment: You are welcome. :-) You can learn more by reading [`perldoc -f use`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html).

Comment: That's not the point. Empty import list is just a special case of the [style](http://p3rl.org/style) decision to always declare the import. I should really get around writing a [Critic policy](http://p3rl.org/Perl::Critic::Policy) for that. Reasons: ① You document where a subroutine comes from. Imagine having 20 `use` statements and now first you need to find out where it's from in order to look it up in the documentation. ② The `import` subroutine can do all sorts of side effects, not only importing symbols. It's a good idea to minimise side effects unless you really want/need them.

Answer (score 3):

Generally DateTime formatters will both parse a string to and format a string from a DateTime object. ->parse_datetime will give you a DateTime object from a string, and ->format_datetime will give you a string from a DateTime object. When you have a formatter you want to use to both deserialize and reserialize your dates, you can use it in a few different ways:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

use DateTime;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

use 5.012;

my $now = DateTime->now(time_zone => 'local');
say $now; ### '2011-07-01T08:22:03' - converted to string with default formatter

my $p = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
    pattern     => '%d/%m-%Y',
    time_zone   => 'UTC',
    );
say $p->format_datetime($now); ### use the parser against a DateTime
                               ### '01/07-2011'

$now->set_formatter($p); ### Set the parser as the default string 
                         ### formatter for the DateTime object
say $now; ### '01/07-2011' -- from formatter

### Or set it at object construction
my $now2 = DateTime->now( time_zone => 'local',
                          formatter => $p,
                        );
say $now2; ### '01/07-2011' - from formatter
```