# Which module do I use to get the content of a HTML element?

Tags: perl, web-scraping

I have a Internet explorer navigate to a page and I am able to get the page in an array. What I want to do is get content of a div file, for example the page returns

```
<div class="someClass">Text in div</div>
```

and I want to get that text, how would I do it? I was thinking of trying

```
->content("someClass");
```

but it wouldn't work.

Comment: Please do not ask several questions in one question, Stack Overflow does not work well that way. I have removed the latter part, you can still get the original text from [revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11056483/revisions). If you think that part is substantially different from the primary question, take the text and [open a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Thanks for notifying me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [Web::Query](http://p3rl.org/Web%3a%3aQuery):

```
use Web::Query qw();
use WWW::Mechanize qw();
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;
$mech->get('file:///tmp/so11056483.html');
Web::Query
    ->new_from_html($mech->content)
    ->find('div.someClass')
    ->text
```

expression returns the string `Text in div`

Comment: how would I put that in a variable?

Comment: Use the [ordinary assignment operator](http://p3rl.org/op#Assignment-Operators), like with any other expression.

Comment: didn't work, is there a way of doing this using www::mechanize?

Comment: what's the qw() after the names?

Comment: An empty list, constructed with the [`qw` operator](http://p3rl.org/op#qw%2fSTRING%2f). Read http://stackoverflow.com/q/6547453#comment-7714112 for the reason.

Comment: when it says can't locate WWW/Mechanize.pm does that mean I have to install the module by doing cpan WWW::Mechanize?

Comment: [Yes.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865/whats-the-easiest-way-to-install-a-missing-perl-module)

Comment: it says "Running make install make test had returned bad status, won't install without force." How do I instal lthis?

Comment: [Open a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and provide the full log.