# Perl get text between tags

Tags: perl

I tried so many codes that I found on internet but none of them would work.

I have a HTML code something like this.

```
<div class="usernameHolder">Username: user123</div>
```

what I want is get the text user123 from this line of code, of course this code is with the rest of the HTML content (an HTML page) Can anyone point me to the right direction?

```
$text = @source=~ /Username:\s+(.*)\s+</;
print $text;
```

but it won't return anything.

Comment: See [Parsing HTML the Cthulhu Way](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html), and [Regex to Match Open Tags Except XHTML Self-Contained Tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: @Grigor - be carefull with your sigils - '@source' != '$source'.

Comment: You can make perl answer your question by adding `use warnings` to your code. `Applying pattern match (m//) to @array will act on scalar(@array) at...`

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056483/which-module-do-i-use-to-get-the-content-of-a-html-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the HTML is in a string:

```
$source = '<div class="usernameHolder">Username: user123</div>';

# Allow optional whitespace before or after the username value.
$text = $source=~ /Username:\s*(.*?)\s*</;

print $1 . "\n";   # user123
```

If the HTML is in an array:

```
@source = (
    '<p>Some text</p>',
    '<div class="usernameHolder">Username: user123</div>',
    '<p>More text</p>'
);
# Combine the matching array elements into a string.
$matching_lines = join "",grep(/Username:\s*(.*?)\s*</, @source);

# Extract the username value.
$text = $matching_lines =~ /Username:\s*(.*?)\s*</;

print $1 . "\n";   # user123
```

A more-compact version using an array:

```
@source = (
    '<p>Some text</p>',
    '<div class="usernameHolder">Username: user123</div>',
    '<p>More text</p>'
);

# Combine the matching array elements in a string, and extract the username value.
$text = (join "",grep(/Username:\s*(.*?)\s*</, @source)) =~ /Username:\s*(.*?)\s*</;

print $1 . "\n";   # user123
```

Answer (score 2):

Your second `\s+` doesn't match anything, since there is no space between `user123` and the following tag.

How about this?

```
/Username:\s*(.*?)\s*</
```

Here, `\s*` is discarding spaces *if there are any*, and `.*?` is there so that you don't grab most of the document in the process. (See greedy vs. non-greedy)

Comment: This answer is wrong. You cannot apply a pattern match to an array, and that's why nothing is printing. (well, you *can*, but then the array is put in scalar context and returning its size, not its content)

Comment: @TLP: Oh. You're right, that's an error *too*. I didn't even notice that, I focused on the regexp not fitting the use case. It doesn't make anything I wrote wrong, it just makes it incomplete.